# knife ec2 create in combination with knife vault update

Tags: amazon-ec2, chef-infra, chef-recipe, knife

I normally use the first command below after bootstrapping a new node in order to register it's keys with my creds vault/databag. In order words let's assume i have node1 and node2 registered, creating a node3 after updating node1 and node2 will require me to run the `knife vault update` command before running my user-creation cookbook.

`knife vault update creds testuser -A admin -S "name:nodes*" -M client -J test.json`

That said, i am trying to incorporate this into newly created nodes on AWS using `knife ec2 create`. I am using this to create my ec2 instances

`knife ec2 server create -I ami-xxxxx -f m3.medium -S secretkey -i keys.pem --ssh-user root --region us-west-1 --security-group-ids sg-xxxx --subnet subnet-xxxxx --associate-public-ip -N node3`

I want to be able to create users while the nodes are being created. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

There is [an option to update vault item](https://docs.chef.io/install_bootstrap.html#use-bootstrap-vault-item) on bootstrap

```
--bootstrap-vault-item 'vault::item'
```

I see it's [supported](https://github.com/chef/knife-ec2/blob/a0b8a0bd1c5c671c27c09770dd87e46da9718a1c/lib/chef/knife/ec2_server_create.rb#L398) by knife ec2 aswell.